# Mainframe COBOL db2 delete program

Tags: db2, cursor, cobol, mainframe

Detail question is my next question -- please check below link

[DB2/Cursor program working in cobol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251141/db2-cursor-program-working-in-cobol)

Comment: you should be asking your client what they want instead of random internet strangers.

Comment: @SaggingRufus well thanku for ur valuable suggestion. it didn't occur to me at all!!!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a 2 step process. First identify the records that are to be deleted and then delete those records in the 2nd step. I think, you'll Not be able to delete the records from the same table you are fetching, that's why 2 steps.

Step 1:

```
Select Concat(A.ClientId, A.PhoneNumber, A.Timestamp) from MyTable A
 Where Concat(A.ClientId, A.PhoneNumber, A.Timestamp)
Not IN (Select Concat(B.ClientId, B.PhoneNumber, Min(B.Timestamp))
    from MyTable B
    Group by B.ClientId, B.PhoneNumber);
```

Step 2:

```
Delete from MyTable
 Where Concat(A.ClientId, A.PhoneNumber, A.Timestamp) IN (all the values you got from Step1);
```

You can run step 1, create a dataset to get all the values and use that dataset in step 2. If you are running dynamic then a cut paste will do, else you'll have to modify the dataset using SORT to create a query out of it. That will be another Step in the middle of step 1 and 2.

.

Comment: adding to my above question , before deleting rows from table i have to take back up into tape file and also create a report like which and how many records are deleted ?

Comment: below is my logic , please someone tell me whtr this will work ? <br / >