# DB2/Cursor program working in cobol

Tags: sql, db2, cursor, cobol, mainframe

My requirement is to delete data from db2 table which contains duplicate phone num(invalid phone num, set of 16 phone numbers which is hardcoded).And one phone num should be retained , that depends on sequence number(minimum value).

consider main table has following data : PHONE_TAB

```
Client_Id   Phone_num  Seq_num
 1234        45678       15   --- delete
 4444        55555       45
 1234        45678       10   ---should be retained 
 5555        22222       25
 1234        45678       20   ---  delete
 1234        45678       11   ---  delete
```

Note : also i have to move the rows which will be deleted to output tape file before deleting to take backup.

Have come up with the below logic,
Declaring cursor :

```
EXEC SQL
  DECLARE CUR1 CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR
   SELECT * FROM PHONE_TAB WHERE PHONE_NUM = 45678
END-EXEC
```

FETCH-PARA

```
EXEC SQL
 FETCH CUR1 INTO :DCLGEN_CLIENT_ID
                :DCLGEN_PHONE_NUM
                :DCLGEN_SEQ_NUM
END-EXEC
```

VALIDATE-PARA

```
EXEC SQL
 SELECT MIN(SEQ_NUM) FROM PHONE_TAB
 WHERE CLIENT_ID = :DCLGEN_CLIENT_ID
       PHONE_NUM = :DCLGEN_PHONE_NUM GROUP BY CLIENT_ID AND PHONE_NUM
       INTO WS_MIN
END-EXEC

EVALUATE TRUE 
 WHEN SEQ_NUM > WS_MIN 
      PERFORM BACKUP-PARA
 WHEN OTHER
      PERFORM FETCH-PARA
```

Finally , DELETE-PARA

```
EXEC SQL
  DELETE FROM PHONE_TAB WHERE CURRENT CURSOR
END-EXEC
```

Can someone tell me whether this logic is right ?
My doubt is whether it will do mass deletion without taking backup to tape file?

Thanks

Comment: Please explain why this is different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152124/mainframe-cobol-db2-delete-program (which may should get the additional information edited in)

Comment: @SimonSobisch firstly i tried to edit same question , but couldn't do it clearly! It is different in way that i hve included code here and usage of cursor's ..

Comment: @SimonSobisch apologies for confusion! since im new to stack over flow.. didn't knw hw to post code and queries in the begining

Comment: One suggestion, write the backup dataset only after deleting the row from the table. You can keep client Id, seq number in working storage and write those details only after delete. Why? Because if you write before deleting then there is a chance that your delete is Not successful and even then you may be telling that you've deleted that record. I am also not sure how you are handling sqlcode 0/100 in your delete query. If you are saying sqlcode 100 is fine then you may not want to write that record in output.

Comment: @user6542823 :  have included error handling condition after every SQL query statements .Like, if 0 perform abc para and if 100 perform ABEND para. . could you tell me whether my logic wud satisfy the requirement ? like  for 1 FETCH statement how many rows would it delete ?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete them all in one go with the following SQL

```
DELETE FROM PHONE_TAB A
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PHONE_TAB B
                WHERE A.PHONE_NUM = B.PHONE_NUM AND
                      A.SEQ_NUM > B.SEQ_NUM)
```

It works by deleting all rows where another row exists that has the same phone number and a lower sequence number.

You can check that it deletes the right rows by first running it with a select, like this

```
SELECT * FROM PHONE_TAB A
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PHONE_TAB B
                WHERE A.PHONE_NUM = B.PHONE_NUM AND
                      A.SEQ_NUM > B.SEQ_NUM)
```

If you need to backup the rows, you can run the select and then delete the rows.